# Yacc Parser not recognising an INT

Tags: parsing, yacc, lex

I want to build a parser for c language using lex and yacc. What i want to do is replace the structure for(i,0..50) with for(i=0;i<50;i++) and for(50) with for(i=0;i<50;i++) where i is any unused variable in the program. Until now what I have done is following....

My lex file contents ..

```
D           [0-9]
L           [a-zA-Z_]
H           [a-fA-F0-9]
E           [Ee][+-]?{D}+
FS          (f|F|l|L)
IS          (u|U|l|L)*

%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include "y.tab.h"

void count();
%}

%%
"/*"            { comment(); }

"auto"          { count(); return(AUTO); }
"break"         { count(); return(BREAK); }
"case"          { count(); return(CASE); }
"char"          { count(); return(CHAR); }
"const"         { count(); return(CONST); }
"continue"      { count(); return(CONTINUE); }
"default"       { count(); return(DEFAULT); }
"do"            { count(); return(DO); }
"double"        { count(); return(DOUBLE); }
"else"          { count(); return(ELSE); }
"enum"          { count(); return(ENUM); }
"extern"        { count(); return(EXTERN); }
"float"         { count(); return(FLOAT); }
"for"           { count(); return(FOR); }
"goto"          { count(); return(GOTO); }
"if"            { count(); return(IF); }
"int"           { count(); return(INT); }
"long"          { count(); return(LONG); }
"register"      { count(); return(REGISTER); }
"return"        { count(); return(RETURN); }
"short"         { count(); return(SHORT); }
"signed"        { count(); return(SIGNED); }
"sizeof"        { count(); return(SIZEOF); }
"static"        { count(); return(STATIC); }
"struct"        { count(); return(STRUCT); }
"switch"        { count(); return(SWITCH); }
"typedef"       { count(); return(TYPEDEF); }
"union"         { count(); return(UNION); }
"unsigned"      { count(); return(UNSIGNED); }
"void"          { count(); return(VOID); }
"volatile"      { count(); return(VOLATILE); }
"while"         { count(); return(WHILE); }

{D}*                    { count(); printf(" __ 0 -"); return INTCON; }
".."            { printf("is it matching with ddot ? "); count(); return DDOT; }
{L}({L}|{D})*       { count(); return(check_type()); }


0[xX]{H}+{IS}?      { count(); printf("__ 1 %d",atoi(yytext)); return(CONSTANT); }
0{D}+{IS}?      { count(); printf("__ 2 %d",atoi(yytext)); return(CONSTANT); }
{D}+{IS}?       { count(); printf("__ 3 %d",atoi(yytext)); return(CONSTANT); }
L?'(\\.|[^\\'])+'   { count(); printf("__ 4 %d",atoi(yytext)); return(CONSTANT); }

{D}+{E}{FS}?        { count(); printf("__ 5 %d",atoi(yytext)); return(CONSTANT); }
{D}*"."{D}+({E})?{FS}?  { count(); printf("__ 6 %d",atoi(yytext)); return(CONSTANT); }
{D}+"."{D}*({E})?{FS}?  { count(); printf("__",atoi(yytext)); return(CONSTANT); }

L?\"(\\.|[^\\"])*\" { count(); return(STRING_LITERAL); }

"..."           { count(); return(ELLIPSIS); }
">>="           { count(); return(RIGHT_ASSIGN); }
"<<="           { count(); return(LEFT_ASSIGN); }
"+="            { count(); return(ADD_ASSIGN); }
"-="            { count(); return(SUB_ASSIGN); }
"*="            { count(); return(MUL_ASSIGN); }
"/="            { count(); return(DIV_ASSIGN); }
"%="            { count(); return(MOD_ASSIGN); }
"&="            { count(); return(AND_ASSIGN); }
"^="            { count(); return(XOR_ASSIGN); }
"|="            { count(); return(OR_ASSIGN); }
">>"            { count(); return(RIGHT_OP); }
"<<"            { count(); return(LEFT_OP); }
"++"            { count(); return(INC_OP); }
"--"            { count(); return(DEC_OP); }
"->"            { count(); return(PTR_OP); }
"&&"            { count(); return(AND_OP); }
"||"            { count(); return(OR_OP); }
"<="            { count(); return(LE_OP); }
">="            { count(); return(GE_OP); }
"=="            { count(); return(EQ_OP); }
"!="            { count(); return(NE_OP); }
","                     { count(); return(','); }
";"         { count(); return(';'); }
("{"|"<%")      { count(); return('{'); }
("}"|"%>")      { count(); return('}'); }
","         { count(); return(','); }
":"         { count(); return(':'); }
"="         { count(); return('='); }
"("         { count(); return('('); }
")"         { count(); return(')'); }
("["|"<:")      { count(); return('['); }
("]"|":>")      { count(); return(']'); }
"."         { count(); return('.'); }
"&"         { count(); return('&'); }
"!"         { count(); return('!'); }
"~"         { count(); return('~'); }
"-"         { count(); return('-'); }
"+"         { count(); return('+'); }
"*"         { count(); return('*'); }
"/"         { count(); return('/'); }
"%"         { count(); return('%'); }
"<"         { count(); return('<'); }
">"         { count(); return('>'); }
"^"         { count(); return('^'); }
"|"         { count(); return('|'); }
"?"         { count(); return('?'); }

[ \t\v\n\f]     { count(); }
.           { /* ignore bad characters */ }

%%

yywrap()
{
    return(1);
}


comment()
{
    char c, c1;

loop:
    while ((c = input()) != '*' && c != 0)
        putchar(c);

    if ((c1 = input()) != '/' && c != 0)
    {
        unput(c1);
        goto loop;
    }

    if (c != 0)
        putchar(c1);
}


int column = 0;

void count()
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; yytext[i] != '\0'; i++)
        if (yytext[i] == '\n')
            column = 0;
        else if (yytext[i] == '\t')
            column += 8 - (column % 8);
        else
            column++;

    ECHO;
}


int check_type()
{
/*
* pseudo code --- this is what it should check
*
*   if (yytext == type_name)
*       return(TYPE_NAME);
*
*   return(IDENTIFIER);
*/

/*
*   it actually will only return IDENTIFIER
*/
    //printf("...%s...",yytext);
    return(IDENTIFIER);
}
```

and my Yacc contents are ...

```
%union {int n; char *v;}
%token IDENTIFIER CONSTANT STRING_LITERAL SIZEOF INTCON
%token PTR_OP INC_OP DEC_OP LEFT_OP RIGHT_OP LE_OP GE_OP EQ_OP NE_OP
%token AND_OP OR_OP MUL_ASSIGN DIV_ASSIGN MOD_ASSIGN ADD_ASSIGN
%token SUB_ASSIGN LEFT_ASSIGN RIGHT_ASSIGN AND_ASSIGN
%token XOR_ASSIGN OR_ASSIGN TYPE_NAME

%token TYPEDEF EXTERN STATIC AUTO REGISTER
%token CHAR SHORT INT LONG SIGNED UNSIGNED FLOAT DOUBLE CONST VOLATILE VOID
%token STRUCT UNION ENUM ELLIPSIS

%token CASE DEFAULT IF ELSE SWITCH WHILE DO FOR GOTO CONTINUE BREAK RETURN
%token DDOT
%start translation_unit
%%

primary_expression
    : IDENTIFIER
    | CONSTANT
    | INTCON
    | STRING_LITERAL
    | '(' expression ')'
    ;

postfix_expression
    : primary_expression
    | postfix_expression '[' expression ']'
    | postfix_expression '(' ')'
    | postfix_expression '(' argument_expression_list ')'
    | postfix_expression '.' IDENTIFIER
    | postfix_expression PTR_OP IDENTIFIER
    | postfix_expression INC_OP
    | postfix_expression DEC_OP
    ;

argument_expression_list
    : assignment_expression
    | argument_expression_list ',' assignment_expression
    ;

unary_expression
    : postfix_expression
    | INC_OP unary_expression
    | DEC_OP unary_expression
    | unary_operator cast_expression
    | SIZEOF unary_expression
    | SIZEOF '(' type_name ')'
    ;

unary_operator
    : '&'
    | '*'
    | '+'
    | '-'
    | '~'
    | '!'
    ;

cast_expression
    : unary_expression
    | '(' type_name ')' cast_expression
    ;

multiplicative_expression
    : cast_expression
    | multiplicative_expression '*' cast_expression
    | multiplicative_expression '/' cast_expression
    | multiplicative_expression '%' cast_expression
    ;

additive_expression
    : multiplicative_expression
    | additive_expression '+' multiplicative_expression
    | additive_expression '-' multiplicative_expression
    ;

shift_expression
    : additive_expression
    | shift_expression LEFT_OP additive_expression
    | shift_expression RIGHT_OP additive_expression
    ;

relational_expression
    : shift_expression
    | relational_expression '<' shift_expression
    | relational_expression '>' shift_expression
    | relational_expression LE_OP shift_expression
    | relational_expression GE_OP shift_expression
    ;

equality_expression
    : relational_expression
    | equality_expression EQ_OP relational_expression
    | equality_expression NE_OP relational_expression
    ;

and_expression
    : equality_expression
    | and_expression '&' equality_expression
    ;

exclusive_or_expression
    : and_expression
    | exclusive_or_expression '^' and_expression
    ;

inclusive_or_expression
    : exclusive_or_expression
    | inclusive_or_expression '|' exclusive_or_expression
    ;

logical_and_expression
    : inclusive_or_expression
    | logical_and_expression AND_OP inclusive_or_expression
    ;

logical_or_expression
    : logical_and_expression
    | logical_or_expression OR_OP logical_and_expression
    ;

conditional_expression
    : logical_or_expression
    | logical_or_expression '?' expression ':' conditional_expression
    ;

assignment_expression
    : conditional_expression
    | unary_expression assignment_operator assignment_expression
    ;

assignment_operator
    : '='
    | MUL_ASSIGN
    | DIV_ASSIGN
    | MOD_ASSIGN
    | ADD_ASSIGN
    | SUB_ASSIGN
    | LEFT_ASSIGN
    | RIGHT_ASSIGN
    | AND_ASSIGN
    | XOR_ASSIGN
    | OR_ASSIGN
    ;

expression
    : assignment_expression
    | expression ',' assignment_expression
    ;

constant_expression
    : conditional_expression
    ;

declaration
    : declaration_specifiers ';'
    | declaration_specifiers init_declarator_list ';'
    ;

declaration_specifiers
    : storage_class_specifier
    | storage_class_specifier declaration_specifiers
    | type_specifier
    | type_specifier declaration_specifiers
    | type_qualifier
    | type_qualifier declaration_specifiers
    ;

init_declarator_list
    : init_declarator
    | init_declarator_list ',' init_declarator
    ;

init_declarator
    : declarator
    | declarator '=' initializer
    ;

storage_class_specifier
    : TYPEDEF
    | EXTERN
    | STATIC
    | AUTO
    | REGISTER
    ;

type_specifier
    : VOID
    | CHAR
    | SHORT
    | INT
    | LONG
    | FLOAT
    | DOUBLE
    | SIGNED
    | UNSIGNED
    | struct_or_union_specifier
    | enum_specifier
    | TYPE_NAME
    ;

struct_or_union_specifier
    : struct_or_union IDENTIFIER '{' struct_declaration_list '}'
    | struct_or_union '{' struct_declaration_list '}'
    | struct_or_union IDENTIFIER
    ;

struct_or_union
    : STRUCT
    | UNION
    ;

struct_declaration_list
    : struct_declaration
    | struct_declaration_list struct_declaration
    ;

struct_declaration
    : specifier_qualifier_list struct_declarator_list ';'
    ;

specifier_qualifier_list
    : type_specifier specifier_qualifier_list
    | type_specifier
    | type_qualifier specifier_qualifier_list
    | type_qualifier
    ;

struct_declarator_list
    : struct_declarator
    | struct_declarator_list ',' struct_declarator
    ;

struct_declarator
    : declarator
    | ':' constant_expression
    | declarator ':' constant_expression
    ;

enum_specifier
    : ENUM '{' enumerator_list '}'
    | ENUM IDENTIFIER '{' enumerator_list '}'
    | ENUM IDENTIFIER
    ;

enumerator_list
    : enumerator
    | enumerator_list ',' enumerator
    ;

enumerator
    : IDENTIFIER
    | IDENTIFIER '=' constant_expression
    ;

type_qualifier
    : CONST
    | VOLATILE
    ;

declarator
    : pointer direct_declarator
    | direct_declarator
    ;

direct_declarator
    : IDENTIFIER
    | '(' declarator ')'
    | direct_declarator '[' constant_expression ']'
    | direct_declarator '[' ']'
    | direct_declarator '(' parameter_type_list ')'
    | direct_declarator '(' identifier_list ')'
    | direct_declarator '(' ')'
    ;

pointer
    : '*'
    | '*' type_qualifier_list
    | '*' pointer
    | '*' type_qualifier_list pointer
    ;

type_qualifier_list
    : type_qualifier
    | type_qualifier_list type_qualifier
    ;


parameter_type_list
    : parameter_list
    | parameter_list ',' ELLIPSIS
    ;

parameter_list
    : parameter_declaration
    | parameter_list ',' parameter_declaration
    ;

parameter_declaration
    : declaration_specifiers declarator
    | declaration_specifiers abstract_declarator
    | declaration_specifiers
    ;

identifier_list
    : IDENTIFIER
    | identifier_list ',' IDENTIFIER
    ;

type_name
    : specifier_qualifier_list
    | specifier_qualifier_list abstract_declarator
    ;

abstract_declarator
    : pointer
    | direct_abstract_declarator
    | pointer direct_abstract_declarator
    ;

direct_abstract_declarator
    : '(' abstract_declarator ')'
    | '[' ']'
    | '[' constant_expression ']'
    | direct_abstract_declarator '[' ']'
    | direct_abstract_declarator '[' constant_expression ']'
    | '(' ')'
    | '(' parameter_type_list ')'
    | direct_abstract_declarator '(' ')'
    | direct_abstract_declarator '(' parameter_type_list ')'
    ;

initializer
    : assignment_expression
    | '{' initializer_list '}'
    | '{' initializer_list ',' '}'
    ;

initializer_list
    : initializer
    | initializer_list ',' initializer
    ;

statement
    : labeled_statement
    | compound_statement
    | expression_statement
    | selection_statement
    | iteration_statement
    | jump_statement
    ;

labeled_statement
    : IDENTIFIER ':' statement
    | CASE constant_expression ':' statement
    | DEFAULT ':' statement
    ;

compound_statement
    : '{' '}'
    | '{' statement_list '}'
    | '{' declaration_list '}'
    | '{' declaration_list statement_list '}'
    ;

declaration_list
    : declaration
    | declaration_list declaration
    ;

statement_list
    : statement
    | statement_list statement
    ;

expression_statement
    : ';'
    | expression ';'
    ;

selection_statement
    : IF '(' expression ')' statement
    | IF '(' expression ')' statement ELSE statement
    | SWITCH '(' expression ')' statement
    ;

iteration_statement
    : WHILE '(' expression ')' statement
    | DO statement WHILE '(' expression ')' ';'
    | FOR '(' expression_statement expression_statement ')' statement
    | FOR '(' expression_statement expression_statement expression ')' statement
    | FOR '(' IDENTIFIER ',' INTCON DDOT INTCON ')' statement
    ;

jump_statement
    : GOTO IDENTIFIER ';'
    | CONTINUE ';'
    | BREAK ';'
    | RETURN ';'
    | RETURN expression ';'
    ;

translation_unit
    : external_declaration  
    | translation_unit external_declaration  
    ;

external_declaration
    : function_definition
    | declaration
    ;

function_definition
    : declaration_specifiers declarator declaration_list compound_statement
    | declaration_specifiers declarator compound_statement
    | declarator declaration_list compound_statement
    | declarator compound_statement
    ;



%%
#include <stdio.h>

extern char yytext[];
extern int column;

void yyerror(char *s){
    fflush(stdout);
    printf("\n%*s\n%*s\n", column, "^", column, s);
}


void main() {
    yyparse();
 }
```

And I am trying to parse the following test.c file...

```
int main(){
    int a,b;
    for(a=0;a<10;a++){
        for(b,0..40){
            printf("Hello World");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but the problem is that it recognizes 0. as a float in for(b,0..50) instead of recognizing it as INTCON DDOT INTCON. and gives syntax error. Can you please suggest me where am i doing wrong ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic problem for parsing PASCAL and other languages that use `..` as a token.  The problem is that an integer followed directly by a `..` can be treated as a float followed by a `.`.

The usual solution is to use lex's trailing context operator (`/`) to add a special rule for this case:

```
{D}+/..                    { count(); yylval.n = atoi(yytext); return INTCON; }
```

You need this rule in addition to the normal digit rule.  If you allowed hex float constants, you'd need a similar rule for hex ints followed by a `..`, but it looks like you don't.

Comment: It is working great. But still it is not recognizing 0 in return 0; as INTCON . Any hint ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the lexical grammar you've designed has a flaw.

Lex is specified to return the longest match and for the input `0..` the longest match is when this rule for a float literal, `{D}+"."{D}*({E})?{FS}?`, is considered.